# visible button does not work on page 1 pagination asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

when logged in user ID matches the data ID on top page, it should show edit on it's bottom. It worked fine but does not work on page 1 of pagination.But when user goes to page 2 and return to page 1 it shows edit button as my expectation. What can be the solution to show edit button from beginning if the ID matches. Thank you in advance.

I'm doing:

```
<asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible='<%# Label4.Text.ToString() == Eval("user_id").ToString()? true:false %>' Width="100px" />
```

to compare ID and using grid view for pagination.

Comment: Please add some sample code so it will be easier for others to see what's really going on. Make sure you clearly express the problem you have.

Comment: I'm doing "<asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Visible='<%# Label4.Text.ToString() == Eval("user_id").ToString()? true:false %>' Width="100px" />" to compare ID.  This does not work if the pagination page is just 1.

Comment: It sounds like your logic isn't loading the userID when you initially load the page. It's there after you reload, so make sure it's being set on the first visit.

Comment: Solved it. Yes, the userID was not loaded at initial page load. Thank you @levelonehuman and Nimeshka Srimal for your reply and help.